# How to get the information of processor on ubuntu 17.10 distribution

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, cpu

How to check the processor of ubuntu distribution whether it is amd, arm or s390x?

Comment: [I downvoted this because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) you clearly did not bother using google. Had you used [Google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ubuntu+get+processor+type) you would have come to [this site](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-cpu-information/), which shows the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use :

1. the `lscpu` command to get the information about your processor
2. `lshw -C CPU`
3. `dmidecode -t 4` or `dmidecode --type processor`
4. `inxi -C`
5. `hardinfo`

Answer (score 3):

To print the processor type you can use the command `uname -p`

Answer (score 2):

open the terminal using `ctrl+alt+t`

then type the following in the command prompt and hit `enter`

`dpkg --print-architecture`

will output the primary architecture of the machine it's run on. This will be armhf on a machine running 32-bit ARM Debian or Ubuntu (or a derivative), arm64 on a machine running 64-bit ARM.

and if you want more information on your cpu as mentioned by @GAD3R, type the following in the command prompt and hit `enter`

`lscpu`

Answer (score 2):

On the command line you can try `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Or replace *cat* with *more* to scroll through.